# Ayuda con herramienta de windows forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015

Lo que pasa es que debo hacer un buscaminas de 300 casillas, pero no se con que herramienta crear el cuadro, alguien me podria hacer el favor de decirme cual herramienta me servirá para colocarle el código de aleatorio y que me funcione el juego?
Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es por medio del control botón, aquí te dejo el código de como lo haría yo.

Primero haría un método que me permita generar las posiciones en donde se encontrarán las minas

```
private int[] getMinas()
{
    int[] minas = new int[20]; //aquí pones cuantas minas quieres que hayan
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        int pos = rand.Next(1, 301); //serían del 1 al 300
        if (!(minas.Contains(pos)))
            minas[i] = pos;
        else
            i--; //para repetir nuevamente que se ejecute un random para la posición actual, en caso de que haya salido una mina que ya existía.
    }
    return minas;
}
```

Después tienes que hacer un método que será el que se dispare cuando al presionar el botón verifique sí se encuentra o no una mina

```
private void dynamicbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            btn.Enabled = false; //desactivas el botón para que no lo vuelvan a presionar
            if (btn.Name.Contains("Mina")) //verificas sí el botón es de mina o no por su nombre, que fue asignado en el método que genera la matriz de minas.
            {
                //Salió una mina
                btn.Text = "X";
            }
            else
            {
                //No salió mina
            }
        }
```

Por último haces una matriz de botones generados de manera dinámica (aquí puedes poner un panel para agregar la matriz)

```
    private void GenerarMatrizBoton()
    {
        int[] minas = getMinas();
        int indice = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Click += new System.EventHandler(dynamicbutton_Click);
                btn.Width = 20;
                btn.Height = 20;
                btn.Location = new Point((j * 20 + 10), (i * 20 + 30));
                if (minas.Contains(indice))
                    btn.Name = "Minas" + indice.ToString();
                else
                    btn.Name = "Libre" + indice.ToString();
                panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
                indice++;
            }
        }
    }
```